# javascript not running 2 times out of 3

Tags: javascript

In a Tomcat environment we invoke a jsp using Ext.Window:

```
var myWindow = new Ext.Window({
   title: myTitle,
   id : "my-window",
   width:430,
   resizable: false,
   height: 320,
   x: 10,
   y: 10,
   closeAction:'destroy',
   constrain: true,
   plain: true,
   bodyStyle:"padding:10 10 0 10px;background:#FFFFFF;background-color:#FFFFFF",
   autoLoad:{
      url: <target url>,
      scripts : true
   }
});
myWindow.show();
```

The  page is a relatively simple jsp; a block of java up front, some javascript scripting, rendering.
The java code populates two string arrays, the javascript uses those arrays to fill two select lists, and the lists are displayed to the user during rendering.

In most environments this works without fail.  However, in one environment that is using load balancing (only difference we can find) we observe a 
recurring pattern:

```
the first attempt shows empty lists
the second shows empty lists
the third shows completed lists
the fourth shows empty lists
the fifth shows empty lists
the sixth shows completed lists
```

and so on.

We have even reduced the  page to a single script with a single alert; same result.

No errors in any logs, app or Tomcat.

Can anybody suggest an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: IMO there's not enough information in the question. Please consider constructing [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes input (if any), expected output vs. actual output. This might help clarify the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been as specific as I can be without exposing too much proprietary code.  I understand if this makes   the question too vague.

Comment: How are the strings being passed from Java to JS?

Comment: Strings are passed through a typical <%=...> mechanism. However, in our simplified test there was no Java code, just <script>alert("here I am");</script>.  Even in that most simple case we saw no alert on the first and second attempts, then saw the alert on the third.

Comment: You don't have to expose proprietary code when you're constructing an example...